# "Read" vs "read as"

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

I tried to explain how to read 6 : 2 aloud in Chinese.  I put:

> It reads ... .

But someone correct me with:

> It reads as ... .

So, I'm wondering which one is correct or idiomatic.

Comment: What do you mean by "6:2"? What does "xxx" refer to?
If you're talking about how to pronounce something that's written down, I'd say neither is correct (native speaking Canadian). Natural would be: "It's pronounced xxx xxx."

Comment: @gotube I meant how to read aloud the written 6:2. I tried to explain it to a Chinese learner in written.  So, I put "It reads xxx xxx." xxx is something in Chinese.

Comment: Ahh. I'm guessing you're typing Chinese characters, but they only appear to me as "6 : 2" (without the spaces) because my English computer can't read them. In your question, I'd replace the actual symbol with "... I explained how to read **a Chinese symbol** aloud..." so others can read it too

Comment: @gotube Actually, 6:2 is not a Chinese symbol.  It may be a score in sports.  I just tried to explain to someone how to read it aloud in Chinese speaking.

Comment: @gotube How would you put in this case if you were I?

Comment: "... I explained how to say "6:2" in Chinese."

Comment: [someone corrected me]

Answer (score 1):

Neither is natural English. Your sentence was wrong. The "corrected" version is correct, but not natural. That person was trying to keep the correct version as close to your original as possible, rather than giving you the most natural version.

Natural is, "I tried to explain how to say '6:2' in Chinese." (no need for "aloud")

Comment: Actually, what I meant is  how I should explain it in English.  But the sentence I wrote "It reads ... " has been corrected as "It reads as..." by someone.  So, I'm wondering which one is correct or natural?  If neither are natural, how should we phrase it?

Comment: Your suggestion ""I tried to explain how to say '6:2' in Chinese." isn't the one I'm looking for.  I'm looking for the answer for "read" vs "read as" or other natural ways to express.

Comment: To be more clear, which of following sentences is correct? "6:2 reads 'six to two'" or "6:2 reads as 'six to two'".  Is the sentence with 'as' correct? or without?

Comment: @dan "6:2 is read as 'six to two' "

Answer (score 1):

Apart from one particular case, (see below) you would not use "reads" with the text following in that way, and you might not be understood if you try to.

If you say "It reads **as** 6:2", you will probably be understood, but it is not idiomatic.

The one context in which you might say "It reads 6:2" is when somebody cannot see it, because it's out of their view, or their vision is bad, and they ask "What does the message say?"

You would most likely reply *It says 6:2*, but you might say *It reads "6:2"*. In the latter case, you are definitely quoting it: for a longer message you can say "It says" and give a paraphrase; but if you say "it reads" you are going to be quoting the exact text of the message.